# Postgres select * after groupby and max

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, max, greatest-n-per-group

Consider a table with an id PK and 26 columns.  There is an index on `(a,b)`

```
id | a | b | c | d | e ... | z |
--------------------------------
```

I'm trying to select the row where the unique pairing of `(a,b)` is most recent.  IE what was the last record for each `(a,b)`  Because ID is autoincrementing, know that the max is the last row.

```
SELECT MAX(id), a, b
FROM table GROUP BY (a, b)
```

However, is there any way to have the `SELECT` show all columns without manually listing them, eg.

```
SELECT MAX(ID), a, b, c ... z
```

I've tried the following to no avail

```
SELECT MAX(ID), *
SELECT MAX(ID), table.*
```

Comment: Use ‘distinct’ for these kind of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, `distinct on` comes handy for this:

```
select distinct on (a, b) t.*
from mytable t
order by a, b, id desc
```

Comment: Ah thanks man.  I had initially tried this but did `order by a,b` and not `order by a, b, id desc`.  Thanks - the id reference solved it!  Just curious, why would it fail if instead if `id desc` I used `b desc` for example?  Like how did you know that `id` is the field that must descend?

I'd really like to display the table sorted by `a, b` and not `a, b, id`, as this is kind of out of order.  I guess I could do a secondary sort with a CTW

Comment: @AdamHughes: this gives you one row per `(a, b)` tuple, and results are ordered by `(a, b)`. The `order by` clause must start with the same columns that you have in the `distinct on` clause, followed by a column (or a set of columns) to identify which record should be kept for each group. You want the record with the latest `id`, so `id desc`.